# Convert pointer to variable?

Tags: c, embedded

`int* pointer=10;`
I want a variable which directly points to the contents of stored adress in `pointer`.

The cause of this act is that I have variable:
`dummy_type a;`
This `a`, has been used many time in my code. I've decide to allocate `a` with my static pool memory. Through the process of allocation I can have just it's pointer. But I need it's dereferenced version having name like `a`.

For example: `int a=5;` then you can extract it's pointer.
But if you have `int* pa=adress` you can not create a dereference `a`. But I need `a`.

Comment: p does not have the address of the integer constant 10. It has the value 10. And the compiler should issue a message that you are trying to convert an integer to a pointer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes the 10 is adress not the stored value. The actual value is stored on adress 10.

Comment: No, the address of `p` is unknown in your example. The content of `p` is value `10` which is converted from integer to a pointer. The pointed to value is at address `10`.

Comment: "Through the process of allocation I can have just it's pointer." That sounds like dynamic memory allocation. How does that go together with "with my static pool memory"

Comment: @Gerhardh no matter static pool or dynamic. the outcome is reference or a pointer, doesn't it?

Comment: The best way to explain is by providing a [mcve], for example show where _"This a, has been used many time in my code"_.

Comment: If I get you right, you want to allocate the address where `a` is stored at runtime using some dynamic allocation. That's not possible. You can make a pointer point to a variable but you cannot move a variable to a dynamic address. The address is allocated by the linker or loader at startup.

Comment: @Gerhardh Can we change the adress of variable? I need something like this. The variable Does not exist. But we abstractically create it using malloc.

Comment: So you have `foo *pa` and you want `foo a`, what about `foo a = *pa;` ?

Comment: You cannot add new variables at runtime. You can use pointers and assign addresses of allocated memory. But then you always need to dereference. If you want to place your variables in specific addresses you might investigate about linker options to adjust placement.

Comment: You cannot do this:  `int *p = 10:`  but you can do this:  `int var = 10;`, then `int *pVar = &var;`.  Now, the address of the variable `var` is pointed to by the pointer `pVar`

Comment: What compiler are you using and what embedded system are you targeting?  Some kind of linker script or section directive might achieve what you want.  You want to control where a static variable gets stored in memory, and your question really has nothing to do with pointers.

Comment: @ryyker it seems the goal is to do something like this `int *pa = <xy>; int a; &a = p;`

Comment: @Ôrel Oh yes, but I think the data will move to the new adress, doesn't it? I want to have the adress maintain.

Comment: @DavidGrayson GCC stm32cubeIDE stm32H7. Why you've remove that macro, that was wrong?

Comment: @Gerhardh I thin your solution must work, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```c
type_t * a_pointer;
#define a (*a_pointer)
```

If you remember to allocate memory at the right time and store your pointer in `a_pointer` then you don't need to change the rest of your code that was written to use `a`.